# Can't install UFW on Amazon Linux server

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum, ufw

I'm trying to install UFW on my amazon linux server with `yum` and here's what I'm getting:

```
[root@ip-XXX-31-43-YYY ~]# sudo yum install ufw
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No package ufw available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@ip-XXX-31-43-YYY ~]#
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can't install via apt-get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `ufw` package for Yum.

Lighten the load on your server, and don't install a firewall on it. Instead, control which ports are open in an AWS Security Group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easiest way to install `ufw` in Amazon Linux 2.

### Install UFW on Amazon Linux 2

> Step 1. Update Amazon Linux 2 system packages.

```
sudo yum update
```

> Step 2. Install and enable `epel` repository on Amazon Linux 2.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel
```

> Step 3. Now, install UFW.

```
yum install --enablerepo="epel" ufw
```

> Step 4. To check the version and installation as well, run:

```
ufw --version
```

**Output:**

```
ufw 0.35
Copyright 2008-2015 Canonical Ltd.
```

And **B0o0ommm**. UFW is installed... Here are some more steps to enable the UFW before using it.

> Step 5. If the installation is fine you can enable it.

```
sudo ufw enable
```

> Step 6. Check the status with:

```
sudo ufw status
```